# Add Column to DataTable before exporting to Excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable, type-conversion, dataview

I have a DataTable that is built like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connString, "storedProcedure", Session("Member"), DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value).Tables(0)
```

Then it is converted to a DataView and exported to Excel like this:

```
Dim dv As New DataView()
dv = dt.DefaultView
Export.CreateExcelFile(dv, strFileName)
```

I want to add another column and fill it with data before I export to Excel. Here's what I'm doing now to add the column:

```
Dim dc As New DataColumn("New Column", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dc.DefaultValue = "N"
dt.Columns.Add(dc)
```

Then to populate it:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim uID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName)
    Dim pID As String = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
    Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [UserID] = " & uID & " AND [PassID] = '" & pID & "'"
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString"))

    myConn.Open()
    myCommand = New SqlCommand(qry, myConn)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

    If reader.Read() Then
        row.Item("New Column") = "Y"
    Else
        row.Item("New Column") = "N"
    End If
Next row
```

But I get a "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." error when I run the app. It doesn't seem to like these lines:

```
Dim uID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName)
Dim pID As String = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
```

I think I have more than one issue here because even if I comment out the loop that fills the data in, the column I created doesn't show up in the Excel file. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, I was grabbing the column name instead of the actual data in the column... because I'm an idiot. **The new column still doesn't show up in the exported Excel file.** Here's the updated code:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connString, "storedProcedure", Session("Member"), DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value).Tables(0)

    Dim dc As New DataColumn("New Column", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dc.DefaultValue = "N"
    dt.Columns.Add(dc)

    'set the values of the new column based on info pulled from db
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString"))
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim uID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row.Item(0))
        Dim pID As String = row.Item(2).ToString
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [UserID] = " & uID & " AND [PassID] = '" & pID & "'"

        myConn.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand(qry, myConn)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            row.Item("New Column") = "Y"
        Else
            row.Item("New Column") = "N"
        End If

        myConn.Close()
    Next row

    dt.AcceptChanges()

    Dim dv As New DataView()
    dv = dt.DefaultView
    Export.CreateExcelFile(dv, strFileName)
```

Comment: Is ColumnName an int? You are trying to convert it to one...

Comment: unless `dt.Columns(0).ColumnName` is all numerals (eg `"12"`), the `Convert.ToInt32` will fail

Comment: Well I'm a dope... I needed to grab the value from that column, not the column name. I've updated my original post.

Comment: This code looks crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, Joel! If you have a suggestion, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my `CreateExcelFile()` method. I inherited the app I'm modifying and assumed the method dynamically read the data in the DataTable and built the spreadsheet. In reality, it was searching the DataTable for specific values and ignored everything else.

2 lines of code later, I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to search your MyTable if it contains a record with the uid and the pid for every row present in your dt table.

If this is your intent then your could write something like this

```
Dim qry As String = "SELECT UserID FROM [MyTable] WHERE [UserID] = @uid AND [PassID] = @pid"
Using  myConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString"))
Using myCommand = new SqlCommand(qry, myConn)
    myConn.Open()
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@uid", OleDbType.Integer)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@pid", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim uID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row(0))
        Dim pID As String = row(1).ToString()
        cmd.Parameters("@uid").Value = uID
        cmd.Parameters("@pid").Value = pID
        Dim result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            row.Item("New Column") = "Y"
        Else
            row.Item("New Column") = "N"
        End If
    Next
End Using
End Using
```

Of course the exporting to Excel of the DataTable changed with the new column should be done AFTER the add of the column and this code that updates it

In this code the opening of the connection and the creation of the command is done before entering the loop over your rows. The parameterized query holds the new values extracted from your ROWS not from your column names and instead of a more expensive ExecuteReader, just use an ExecuteScalar. If the record is found the ExecuteScalar just returns the UserID instead of a full reader.

Comment: My original post probably didn't clearly specify but I am doing the export to Excel AFTER adding the rows. See my updated post. :)

Comment: Well, that's really strange because your datatable (and your DataView) should have the new column. You could try to use the debugger, stop at the line after AcceptChanges and trying to visualize the DataTable and its content using the DataTable visualizer that appears on the debug tooltip. It the column is present then the problem is probably inside the CreateExcelFile but we don't have the code of that method

Comment: Good grief. Okay, Steve, the issue was in CreateExcelFile(). I'm still pretty new to .NET development and since the method was located in an included Export class, I assumed it was some built-in class that dynamically grabbed all the labels and values and spits them out in the Excel file. Apparently it grabs and displays values specific to this project. 2 lines of code later, the issue is resolved.

Comment: If you suggest the Create ExcelFile() method as an answer rather than a comment, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer to give you the credit.

Comment: @Sam, thank you but perhaps you could post your own answer explaining the problem in detail with the appropriate fix applied to your CreateExcelFile and reporting your comment above. See you again on SO